# Extreme input lag with bluetooth keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, bluetooth

When connecting my Logitech MX keyboard directly using bluetooth, I sometimes get an extreme input lag (~1 second) and it even drops some of my keystrokes. This usually happens after the computer has been to sleep.

The MX mouse connected the same way works, and power cycling the keyboard solves it. The behavior is not observed when using the USB dongle, nor when it is connected to my macbook (direct Bluetooth too), only to my Lenovo laptop running Windows 10 (they are both on the same desk). I am pretty sure it is not an issue with weak signal/interference, this looks to me as something of a driver/software issue. Installing the driver package from Logitech did not make a difference.

Anyone know what could be the issue here?

Comment: If it comes with a choice between RF and BT, I would stick with RF (which typically goes through the dongle) as the signal is usually more stable and consistent.  I'm not sure what the nature of the issue is on the technical level — I've seen for myself not all BT devices suffer this issue — but in terms of keyboards *specifically* I've witnessed these symptoms commonly.  I wouldn't be so sure it's buggy behavior or misconfiguration rather than just a limitation with the hardware or BT capabilities itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring some closure to this question. This was an issue with the Lenovo that never occurred with other machines. I'm actually still using that same keyboard (now on an M2 MBP). The last two laptops never had a single issue with this keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things you can try, I'd say when it happens again, try to resolve the lag using the **fourth option** to determine if it is interference or not.

**Edit:** You tried the package from Logitech, but you might be able to also install the driver from Lenovo. Lenovo has a support page on their website for your specific computer model. You can usually access the right page by entering your laptop's serial number on their website, or by selecting your product on the support website. Then you can go to the driver downloads and under Bluetooth you can try installing that package.

**However, if it only happens when waking your computer from sleep, or you can intentionally trigger it by waking from sleep, that is definitely a software/hardware issue and not interference.**

- Plugging the usb receiver into a different USB port.
- Plugging the usb receiver into a USB 2.0 port. (Usually ports that are not painted blue/red/yellow. USB 3.0 ports are typically blue)
- Unplugging/turning off other Bluetooth devices or disabling Bluetooth on your phone.
- Moving the computer and/or keyboard to a different location. (you can also just test by typing while lifting the keyboard up high, or from a few feet away.)
- Moving your wireless router or even disabling the 2.4 Ghz network temporarily to see if that resolves things.
- Turning off nearby wireless printers.
- Installing fresh batteries in your Wireless Keyboard.

Bluetooth broadcasts using the 2.4 GHz frequency, which is the same frequency used by many celluar hotspots, wifi printers, wifi cards/routers, and is, in general, a very noisy band. (Lots of potential for interference.)

If you don't have any success with these, it's possible the Bluetooth antenna has been damaged in some way.

Comment: Thanks! I already ruled out external interference (independent of room/house/city, among other things). Also hardware issue on the Lenovo would affect other BT devices, like the mouse, which works fine. Also, the keyboard works fine when connected to a Mac. The USB receive works, but I do not want to use it, that's the reason I'm asking. I'm on the latest Lenovo drivers for "everything".

Comment: So, as far as I can see, this leaves me with a "software issue" as the most likely candidate. Googling for it just gives me tons of pointless troubleshooting guides, so it is difficult for me to assess if this is a known problem or not.

Comment: This sounds to me like it's a power state issue, particularly because of the pattern of it occurring after coming back from sleep state.  I've personally dealt with workstations in the past where, inexplicably, once the devices go into D3/S0 idle states, they don't wake back up or display faulty behavior subsequently, and require a hard unplug/plug event to regain full functionality.  For those cases, I recall I had to alter the selective suspend state for the USB ports via command line to prevent them from reaching the lower sleep states.

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere until I found someone who said BIOS.
Now, no more problems.
Apparently my new motherboard had initial USB stability issues.